# How to grab Checkbox values in an WebApp

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, web-applications

I found a good example from Nick Young about Checkboxes.

At the end he says just grab the AppID. How can I do this?

I later want to to something like if(IsSelected == true){//some code}

Here is the example:

Models:

```
public class MerchantModel
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class MerchantViewModel
{
    public List<MerchantModel> Merchants { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var merchant1 = new MerchantModel
        {
            AppId = 1,
            Name = "Bob"
        };
        var merchant2 = new MerchantModel
        {
            AppId = 2,
            Name = "Ted"
        };
        var merchant3 = new MerchantModel
        {
            AppId = 3,
            Name = "Alice"
        };

        List<MerchantModel> list = new List<MerchantModel>();
        list.Add(merchant1);
        list.Add(merchant2);
        list.Add(merchant3);

        var model = new MerchantViewModel
        {
            Merchants = list
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MerchantViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TestCheckBoxes.Models.MerchantViewModel

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form action="/default/index" method="post">
            <table>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Merchants.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Merchants[i].IsSelected)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Merchants[i].AppId)
                            @Model.Merchants[i].AppId
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Merchants[i].Name)
                            @Model.Merchants[i].Name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Back in your [HttpPost] method in your controller, you will have a list of MerchantModel's with the bool value either true or false. This way you can check if it's true and just grab the AppId from there.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you want to check the value of checkbox in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried iterating over the Merchants in the model in the post action? Something like this should work:

```
foreach(var m in model.Merchants)
{
    if(m.IsSelected)
    {
        //execute code for this checkbox being checked
    } 
}
```

You could set a breakpoint on the first line of your post method and see what the view has returned to the controller. You should expect a list of merchants with all of the values: AppId, I selected and Name as you are posting all of these values back for each merchant.